# ROracle dbWriteTable creating Oracle TIMESTAMP columns for R DATE columns

Tags: r, oracle

I'm trying to upload some data to my Oracle 11g database using the ROracle package (1.1-10) in 64bit R3.0.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

The ROracle help for `dbWriteTable` states:

> Date and POSIXct map to Oracle DATE ROracle - the ROracle package R -
>   the R application POSIXct - the POSIXct class TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP WITH
>   TIME ZONE TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE

Yet when I run this R code...

```
df <- data.frame(a = as.Date(c("2012-01-01","2013-02-07")), b = c("one","two"))

drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
myconn <- dbConnect(drv, "XXXXX", "XXXXX", "XXXXX")

dbWriteTable(myconn, "MY_TABLE", overwrite = TRUE)
```

It produces a table in Oracle like so...

[image]

Anyone know what gives? Am I reading the help docs wrong?

I've written a function that converts those to DATE in Oracle using the alter table syntax, but I'd much rather not have to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After speaking with the package maintainer, this looks like a bug, and they're hoping to fix it in the next release (which will be 1.1-11)

Comment: It is still not fixed. I just spent couple of hours trying to make PostgreSQL and Oracle `dbWriteTable` to behave consistently.

Comment: 2017 and it's still not fixed

Comment: 2019 (... but I haven't been waiting since 2017)

Comment: 2021 - still getting TIMESTAMPS (... also haven't been waiting, but think I might be by 2023)

Comment: are you using the variable date = TRUE? As my issue is I can get it into oracle in DATE or Timestamp format, but I can't get date without the hours mins and seconds attached.