# dbWriteTable date format

Tags: date, rsqlite

Halo,

im importing tables from MS-Access into R via

```
channel <- odbDriverConnect(...)
foo_import <-sqlFetch(channel,"foo")
```

now Im using the RSQLite for SQL Querys and other stuff

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "foo_table", foo_import)
R_Table <- dbReadTable(conn, "foo_table")
```

the Problem is, that at the sqlFetch step columns including data are still correct, tested with `class(foo_import$Datetime)` which gives `POSIXct` `POSIXt`

After using dbWriteTable and testing the Format with `class(R_Table$Datetime)`
which gives `numeric`
The Dates are just numbers

```
with as.POSIXct(R_Table$Datetime, origin= "1970-01-01")
```

I can transform the column manually. Are they other options to Change the format automatically to a date Format ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847809/roracle-dbwritetable-creating-oracle-timestamp-columns-for-r-date-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914875/roracle-dbwritetable-date-columns) can help

Comment: It doesnt help me :/ I couldnt find a solution for my problem